# Confuse about javascript self-invoking function structure

Tags: javascript

I have not used javascript that much, so I'm confuse about the following code structure. The code is from an external javascript file and the init function was called from index page as "windows.Ux.init(xxx)". I know it's self-invoking function and I assume "windows" object is passed as a parameter to that function. And I assume "exports.Ux" line declares name space and assigned functions to the two variables in the namespace. Are my assumptions correct?

```
( function( exports ) {
   ...
   function init(x) {
   ...
   }
   ..
   exports.Ux = {
      init: init,
      clear: clear
   };

})( window );
```

Comment: Is not called *namespace*, `Ux` is just an object.

Comment: it's just to make the private init(x) method public to the public :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know it's self-invoking function...

It's an *immediately-invoked* function expression (an "IIFE"). (A self-invoking function would be recursive.)

> ...and I assume "windows" object is passed as a parameter to that function.

The value of the `window` global is passed into it, yes. On browsers, that's a reference to the global object. that value is received in the function's `exports` argument.

> And I assume "exports.Ux" line declares name space and assigned functions to the two variables in the namespace.

No, it *creates* an object that is accessible via the `Ux` property on the object `exports` refers to (which is the global object in that case). The object `Ux` refers to has properties referring to functions (loosely, "methods").

Comment: immediately-invoked function expression

Comment: @JaromandaX: I've seen both terms used, but -- oddly -- I normally use that one, too. Changed it.

Comment: I've never seen inline-invoked before - I actually think it's a better description!

Comment: I'm marking yours as a correct answer since it not only explain but also points out my wrong assumptions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This snippet defines a function:

```
(function( exports ) {
  // ...
})
```

And immediately calls it with the argument `window`:

```
(function ...)(window);
```

You can think of the effect of this call as:

- Creating an object with properties called `init` and `clear`
- Assigning this object to `exports.Ux`.

Your function takes a single argument called `exports`, and you call it with the single argument `window`, so you can think of the immediately-invoked function call doing this:

```
window.Ux = {
  init: init,
  clear: clear
}
```

`window` is the global root object in a web browser JavaScript environment.

Answer (score 3):

This is called `IIFE`:

```
( function( exports ) {
   ...
   function init(x) {
   ...
   }
   ..
   exports.Ux = {
      init: init,
      clear: clear
   };

})( window );
```

1. You are passing window object as your param:
2. The second one `exports.Ux` is what your exposing, meaning anything which is not part of `exports.Ux` is not available outside. `Encapsulation`.

So if your IIFE has the following structure:

```
( function( exports ) {
       ...
       function init(x) {
       //you can use it here somePrivate()
       ...
       }
       function somePrivate(){

       }
       ..
       exports.Ux = {
          init: init,
          clear: clear
       };

 })( window );
```

The `somePrivate` function is not exposed to outside world via `window` object, though you can use it inside your other `function`.